# R Studio - How to predict row-by-row and use previous prediction in next one - linear model

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, lm, predict

Sorry if this is unclear, had trouble titling this.

Basically I have a linear model that predicts sales and one of the factors is the previous 10 days of sales. So, when predicting for the next month, I need an estimated number for what the "previous 10 days of sales" is for each day in the month.

I want to use the model to generate these numbers - so, for the first day I'm trying to predict, I have the actual number for the last 10 days of sales. For the day after that, I have 9 days of real data, plus the one predicted number generated. For the day after that, 8 days of real data and two generated, etc.

Not quite sure how to implement this and would appreciate any help. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that came to mind would be a moving average using the predicted data. This gets hard to defend though once you're averaging only predicted data but its a place to start.

```
moving.average = 0

test.dat = rnorm(100, 10,2)

for(i in 1:30){
  moving.average[i] = mean(test.dat[i:i+10])
}
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Definitely harder to defend, but just as an estimate for creating he predicted data. Do you know how I'd be able to implement this though to get the predicted data in the first place? I'm struggling to generate the predicted data because I want to do it line-by-line, using the previous prediction as I go.

Comment: If you haven't built your regression you'll need those coefficients to build the predicted data set. The most basic of Lm is: lm(y~x, data = Matrix)

Comment: I have built the regression, but I'm trying to find a way to not have to predict each row one-by-one - one my regression inputs is the sum of the last 10 days of sales, so I want to find a way to predict the first output, then use that in the next prediction, etc. Sorry if it's unclear

Answer (score 0):

Kathy, get your first 10 data points from... where-ever.  Seed your prediction with it.

```
initialization <- c(9.463, 9.704, 10.475, 8.076, 8.221, 8.509, 
            10.083, 9.572, 8.447, 10.081)

prediction = initialization
```

Here's a silly prediction function that uses the last 10 values:

```
predFn <- function(vec10){
  stopifnot(length(vec10) == 10)
  round(mean(vec10) + 1 , 3)
}
```

Although I usually like to use the `map` family, this one seems like it wants to be a `loop`

```
for(i in 11:20){
  lo = i - 10
  hi = i - 1
  prediction[i] <- predFn(prediction[lo:hi])
}
```

What did we get?

```
prediction
#  [1]  9.463  9.704 10.475  8.076  8.221  8.509 10.083  9.572  8.447 10.081 10.263 10.343 10.407 10.400 10.633 10.874 11.110 11.213
# [19] 11.377 11.670
```

Comment: I know very little about linear models. But if I understand rightly, your full-up problem isn't just about extrapolating a single vector forward.  Rather, you''ve got a data-frame with, say, 5 columns, and you need to predict all 5 values for tomorrow based on the 5 values from 9 days-ago thru today.  And you want to know how to successively append the predictions to the bottom of the dataframe.  RIght?

If my answer was helpful, you might Upvote it, or even accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm very clear with my questions - no, I have a dataframe with say 5 rows and I want to predict all 5 values for tomorrow, the day after tomorrow, etc based on the 10 past rows.

Comment: So you've starting with a dataframe.  It has a _date_ column plus 5 columns x 10 rows.  You've got a linear model (LM) that takes the 10 rows and predicts the next row.  The LM already has its coefficients set, and the LM predicts the next value for each of the 5 columns.  RIght?

Comment: C'mon Kathy.  If somebody takes the time to help you, the least you can do is upvote.  You're not a newbie.